# Is there a way to override inline CSS for `overflow`?

Tags: css

If I want override inline css i must use !important or javascript.

But if I want to override, for example, inline width without important I can use max-width or min-width

Is there some way to override inline

```
  overflow:hidden
```

Comment: if you plan on overriding by editing css files then you can just as easily just delete the inline css

Comment: "But if I want to override, for example, inline width without important I can use max-width or min-width" That's because you're not actually overriding anything. "Override" has a very specific meaning in CSS and it's the width/height properties that are special, not overflow.

Answer (score 2):

***Using CSS***

You can override the inline style using `!important` keyword like below. The inline style background green is override with other color through the class style using `!important` keyword.

```css
.test {
 background-color:#ff00ff !important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="background-color:green">
<h1>
Sample
</h1>
</div>
```

***Using Javascript***

The same you can achieve using JavaScript also.

```js
document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = '#fff000';
```

```html
<div id="test" style="background-color:green">
<h1>
Sample
</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the inline style using `!important` keyword

```css
.overwrite_css{
  background-color: blue !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="overwrite_css" style="background-color: red;font-size: 25px;">
 <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
</h2>
</div>
```

Still not able to override it then try this one

> Note: Using !important ONLY will work here, but I've used  overwrite_css[style]
>   selector to specifically select div having style attribute

The example uses [style] (the attribute selector) to show us that the CSS is targetting the div with the “style” attribute.

```css
.overwrite_css[style]{
  background-color: blue !important;
 }
```

```html
<div class="overwrite_css" style="background-color: red;font-size: 25px;">
 <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only override inline css with

```
!important
```

or you have to use javascript to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change inline css you should use `js`, you can override through `!important` tag but it has high priority so it may affect other css style...

So it's good to use `js` instead of `!important` tag.